# Load attachment form EWS using OAuth authentication (0kb)

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices, attachment, email-attachments

EDIT : Thanks to Ralf, my issue still there but I tried a test program using MS Graph and it's working great !

I am working on a C# console app that connect to one of our mailboxes, read mails, mark it, and download the attachment on a local disk.

App was working great last year. Then, basic authentication no longer worked for ews.

Adding OAuth authentication, app work again for all the steps, except downloading the attachment.

The file is created on the local disk, with correct type, but always empty (0kb).

The OAuth token have (on Azure) :
-Microsoft Graph(Mail.readWrite; User.read)
-Office 365 Exchange Online(full_access_as_app)
-MyApp(ExchangeAccess)

I tried

```
  if (Attachment is FileAttachment && CheckAttachmentExtension(Attachment.Name))
  {
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = Attachment as FileAttachment;

    Path = @"C:\localPath" + "\\" + Attachment.Name;

    Attachment.Load(Path);
  }
```

```
if (Attachment is FileAttachment && CheckAttachmentExtension(Attachment.Name))
{
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = Attachment as FileAttachment;

    Path = @"C:\localPath" + "\\" + Attachment.Name;

    Attachment.Load().Wait();
    Attachment.Load(Path);
}
```

and

```
if (Attachment is FileAttachment && CheckAttachmentExtension(Attachment.Name))
{
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = Attachment as FileAttachment;

    Path = @"C:\localPath" + "\\" + Attachment.Name;

    Attachment.Load().Wait();
    Attachment.Load(Path);

    FileStream theStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    Attachment.Load(theStream);
    theStream.Close();
    theStream.Dispose();
}
```

I am expecting the local file to not be 0kb and have the original content as it was before

I am pretty sure I am missing something, but cannot figure it since few days, reading a lot of topic on this subject

Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Downloading the file requires different permissions (penning the file) than the other methods like getting the files in a folder.  You need to use different permissions.  Either run As an Admin, use a different user, or change permission of the files.

Comment: Do you know wich perm I need please ? 
The OAuth token already have :
-Microsoft Graph(Mail.readWrite; User.read)
-Office 365 Exchange Online(full_access_as_app)
-MyApp(ExchangeAccess)

I quit new with Azure

Thanks

Comment: Try one of these : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-resource-permissions

Comment: Note: EWS is going to be retired in ~2 years for Exchange online. You may want to look for a MS Graph only solution and not invest in EWS.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will search way to do it using MS Graph only :)

Comment: Oauth shouldn't affect the attachment download as in EWS you only have one permission which is full access to the Mailbox. I would suggest you enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications . What library are you using the ews managed API isn't aysnc so it looks like you maybe using a Port of that library? if so the problem is probably a bug in that port eg on one of the ports this is a know issue https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api/issues/55

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I removed the library as I am implementing MS Graph, but I think it's was the EWS Microsoft Library (I didn't made the app, I was in charge of fixing it). Implementing MS Graph take time, but I tried to download attachment from the mailbox and it was working first time :)